# Duplicate rows whilst summing in sql

Tags: sql

I have the below simple query which shows the sum of `valuehome` by `el2`.

If i add another column to my query (see select statement 2) and say only show me `valuehome` where the due date is before today, i.e. it is overdue, I lose my sum on the `valuehome` as the results show a row for each due date

How do I maintain the sum of `valuehome` so that i see one result for `valuehome` even if there is more than one due date.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT el2, statpay, SUM(valuehome) AS Expr1
FROM         dbo.MBO450
GROUP BY el2, statpay
HAVING      (el2 LIKE 'C%') AND (statpay = 84)
ORDER BY el2


SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT el2, statpay, SUM(valuehome) AS Expr1, duedate
FROM         dbo.MBO450
GROUP BY el2, statpay, duedate
HAVING      (el2 LIKE 'C%') AND (statpay = 84) AND (duedate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-24 00:00:00', 102))
ORDER BY el2
```

Thanks Nenad - thats brilliant help - do you know how i would change my static date in the where statement

Don't add duedate to `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` - filter the rows in WHERE condition before grouping :

```
SELECT el2, statpay, SUM(valuehome) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.MBO450
WHERE duedate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-24 00:00:00', 102))
```

so that the static date is todays date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add `duedate` to `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` - filter the rows in `WHERE` condition before grouping :

```
SELECT el2, statpay, SUM(valuehome) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.MBO450
WHERE duedate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-24 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY el2, statpay
HAVING (el2 LIKE 'C%') AND (statpay = 84) 
ORDER BY el2
```

PS: `TOP (100) PERCENT` is useless

PPS: You can also do move `el2` and `statpay` conditions to `WHERE`

PPPS: Replace to `WHERE duedate <= GETDATE()` for dynamic today

Comment: Thanks Nenad - thats brilliant help

Comment: Thanks Nenad - thats brilliant help - do you know how i would change my static date in the where statement 




Don't add duedate to GROUP BY and HAVING - filter the rows in WHERE condition before grouping :
SELECT el2, statpay, SUM(valuehome) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.MBO450
WHERE duedate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-24 00:00:00', 102))  so that the static date is todays date?

Comment: @user2615341 use `GETDATE()`

Comment: Where would i insert GETDATE? - duedate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-24 00:00:00', 102))

Comment: @user2615341 Replace whole `CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-07-24 00:00:00', 102))` with 'GETDATE()'